# Question on Geometry

Tags: geometry, self-learning

I have a B.Ed in Management, but recently developed interest in geometry & would love to study it on my own. Do i need or must have a B.A in Maths before doing this ?

Comment: This can't possibly be a serious question. What are you expecting, that textbooks need to see your diploma before you can read them?

Comment: @Zev Why not just accept that the question was asked in good faith? The OP may be wondering "how much math" is required to study geometry seriously on one's own, apart from the degree. I'm assuming the OP is asking if that (equivalent of a BA in math) is the level of mathematical maturity one needs to study geometry seriously. Put the cynic's hat aside for a moment and take a deep breath.

Comment: It might be helpful to clarify what you mean by "study" - I've seen its use range from "learn about" to "do original research in", and answers to your question will be very different depending on which end of the spectrum you mean.

Comment: Geometry is usually studied at junior high and high school level: anyone can give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

No degree is needed to study math on one's own. And the "knowledge base" in mathematics that one acquires by completing a B.S. in mathematics is not a prerequisite for studying geometry in depth. If you have a passion to study geometry, dig in, starting just where you are!

A nice start might be refreshing your algebra-precalculus skills and reviewing and studying some of the **Khan Academy** video lectures and lessons on [Geometry](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry) to cover the basics. Additionally, you might be obtaining a copy of Marvin Greenberg's [Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716799480), and work your way through it.

Comment: great advice and encouragement! +1